# calculate count for different range in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table like below: "TBL_TEST"

[image]

I want to count table rows for different balance range.

I wrote a query that give correct answere but it is too slow for real data.
could anybody please suggest me other solution?

my own query:

```
 select /*+  PARALLEL(auto) */  COUNT(1),b,max(b1),max(b2) from  ARCHIVE.tbl_test tda,(select  /*+  PARALLEL(auto) */ a.balance *r b2,a.balance *(r-0.1) b1,r*10 AS  B from 
( select   /*+  PARALLEL(auto) */  max(to_number(balance)) balance from ARCHIVE.tbl_test)a ,
(  SELECT
   ROWNUM/10 R
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 10))b  where TDA.BALANCE>B.B1 AND  TDA.BALANCE <=  B.B2
  group by b
order by 2 asc;
```

the output must be:

[image]

Comment: So you want a 10 ranges considering the max balance? Like 0-10%, 10-20%...

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text instead.

Comment: There is a ready-to-use function available: [WIDTH_BUCKET](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions250.htm#SQLRF06163).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using following query:

```
With cte as
(Select 0.1*(level-1) as slvl, 0.1 * level as level, level as rng
   from dual connect by level <= 10),
Maxb as (select max(balance) mbal from your_table)
Select c.rng as range, 
       (c.slvl*m.mbal) as start_range, 
       (c.elvl*m.mbal) as end_range, 
       count(1) as cnt
  From cte c 
  join maxb m On 1=1 
  Left Join your_table t on t.balance between c.slvl*m.mbal + 1 and c.elvl*m.mbal
Group by c.slvl, c.elvl
```

Comment: Spelling of connect was wrong. Now it is corrected. Please check

Comment: I add the output that I expect! please see that